# What is the difference between a Facebook Group and a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, marketing, social-media, website-promotion

I created a Project Management Stack Exchange Facebook Page to help promote the new [Project Management Stack Exchange Site](http://pm.stackexchange.com).

One of the users suggested a Facebook Group instead.  I use Facebook, and I've searched the help pages, but it's not immediately clear to me what the advantages and disadvantages are.

Can you provide a list of uses for Groups and uses for Facebook Pages and perhaps some links to resources that help differentiate one from the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Search Engine Journal - Facebook Group vs Facebook Fan Page.  What's Better?](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/facebook-group-vs-facebook-fan-page-whats-better/7761/) has a table that lists key features and whether or not the particular platform supports the feature.

The main advantage I see with Facebook Groups is that it may be easier to market a Group virally than Fan Page, as bulk invites can be sent on behalf of a Group.

However, Fan Pages have analytics tools to measure traffic, support advertising, and supports the addition of applications.  They also have pretty URLs.  You can also create events.

Answer (score 3):

Group:

- Users are 'members'
- Chat with group members (new)
- You control your group's privacy settings, and only members can add friends to the group.
- A topic meant to collect people who
  have the same interest and to discuss
  it.
- Forums

Page:

- Users are 'fans'
- Anyone can like this.
- Arbitrary things (ie Toast, Lint, Pokemon) that people can 'like'
- Just a wall

You probably want a page unless you think there will be more controlled discussion with forums. For quick user interaction, they can just 'like' your page instead of having to join a group.

Comment: Any links you can include?  Thanks for your answer and the additional points.

Answer (score 1):

The big different that I noticed with fan page. Is that when you add a link or an image it will save in a section links or gallery in fan pages but in a group the link and image will appear in main page but will not have a section for the future.

The best of groups is that all members can receive new posts in their emails. And the chat with everyone. And the groups can be privates.

I think that the groups are great for groupworks. And the fan page is better for marketing. All people with a facebook account will see all your updates and if they like it will see the news in home page. And the events are really usefull, because they can share them with their friends.